Nested elements are not reactive on buildless Solid-js
I have an external script in SOLID js Buildless. No idea why this does not work. fetch API gets data.
the UL elements never gets populated, I think the setSuggestions does not trigger the signals , still no idea why.
Again, this is buildless.
The whole idea is to create an autocomplete component using solid js and bootstrap 5
import { render } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/solid-js/web';
import { createSignal, createEffect, createResource, onCleanup } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/solid-js';
import html from "https://esm.sh/solid-js@1.8.1/html";

function Autocomplete({ apiEndpoint }) {
    const [query, setQuery] = createSignal("");
    const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = createSignal([]);
    const [showDropdown, setShowDropdown] = createSignal(false);

    createEffect(() => {
        const search = query().toLowerCase();
        if (search) {
            console.log("Fetching suggestions for query:", search);
            // uncomment this/comment fetch for test
            // setSuggestions(["abc","def"]);
            fetch(`${apiEndpoint}?name=${search}`)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log("Received data:", data);
                    setSuggestions(data.suggestions || []);
                    setShowDropdown(data.suggestions && data.suggestions.length > 0);
                    console.log("Suggestions after setSuggestions:", suggestions());
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching suggestions:', error));
        } else {
            setSuggestions([]);
            setShowDropdown(false);
        }
    });

    const handleInput = (e) => {
        setQuery(e.target.value);
    };

    const handleSelect = (item) => {
        setQuery(item);
        setShowDropdown(false);
    };

    return html`
        <div class="autocomplete position-relative">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Search..."
            value=${query()}
            onInput=${handleInput}
          />
          ${() => {

        if (showDropdown() && suggestions().length > 0) {
            html`
            <ul class="dropdown-menu show" style="width: 100%;">
              ${suggestions().map((item, i) => html`
                <li key=${i} class="dropdown-item" onMouseDown=${() => handleSelect(item)}>
                  ${item}
                </li>
              `)}
            </ul>
          `} else {
            console.log('no data');
        }
    }}
        </div>
      `;
}

function App() {
    return html`
        <div class="container mt-4">
          <h1>Bootstrap 5 Autocomplete with Solid.js</h1>
          <${Autocomplete} apiEndpoint="/api/properties/" />
        </div>
      `;
}

render(App, document.getElementById('body'));


Another example (simpler) of nested components not being reactive here https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/930493d0-b51b-4a95-b2e9-e3be7844dc75

You are importing multiple Solid-js runtimes in your code:
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal } from "solid-js";
import html from "https://esm.sh/solid-js@1.8.1/html";

Which means you are creating effect in one and trying to run it in another. You should stick to one:
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal } from "solid-js";
import html from 'solid-js/html'


Yep, this is most likely it. Solid.js state should be a singleton, so importing multiple versions will result in a signal from on Solid.js not triggering an effect from the other (in your case, you were passing a signal from one Solid.js into an effect inside html template of the other).
